# Regular expression to match a string (1+ characters) that does NOT end in .ext (extension)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, regex

I need to test a url that it **does not** end with `.asp`

So `test`, `test.html` and `test.aspx` should match, but `test.asp` should not match.

Normally you'd test if the url **does** end with .asp and negate the fact that it matched using the NOT operator in code:

```
if(!regex.IsMatch(url)) { // Do something }
```

In that case the regular expression would be `\.asp$` but in this case I need the regular expression to result in a match.

---

Background: I need to use the regular expression as a route contraint in the ASP.NET MVC `RouteCollection.MapRoute` extension method. The route needs to match all controllers but it should fall through when the controller in the url ends with .asp

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The trick is to use [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

If you need just a yes/no answer:

```
(?<!\.asp)$
```

If you need to match the whole URL:

```
^.*(?<!\.asp)$
```

These regexes will work with any URL where the file name occurs at the end of the URL (i.e. URLs without a query or fragment).  I'm assuming your URLs fit this limitation given the regex .asp$ in your question.  If you want it to work with all URLs, try this:

```
^[^#?]+(?<!\.asp)([#?]|$)
```

Or this if you want the regex to match the whole URL:

```
^[^#?]+(?<!\.asp)([#?].+|$)
```

Comment: The second did the trick it seems, I need to do some tests with more urls, but my first unit tests passes now, so thanks!

Comment: +1 for good info.  Tiny nit pick: the question title notes "1+ characters" and I believe your first two regexes would match empty strings.

Comment: In the context of ASP.NET MVC routing constraints, the URL is inspected in pieces: 
{controller}/{action}/{id}
The regex should match the {controller} part, so 'the end' would not  always be the end of the url, but the end of the {controller} part of the end.

Answer (score 3):

Not a regexp, but c# String.EndsWith method which could easily do the job.

ie

```
string test1 = "me.asp" ;
string test2 = "me.aspx" ;

test1.EndsWith(".asp") // true;
test2.EndsWith(".asp") // false ;
```

Comment: Nope, -1 for not being a regular expression, sorry to be so strict ;-)

Comment: Problem is, in the context of the RouteMap method, it *is* needed.

Comment: @anonymous-one: please read the question: it must be a *regular expression*, this answer does not meet the criteria of the question since it is not a regular expression.

Comment: -1 Agreeing with idea that point is to learn about regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
^((?!\.asp$).)*$
```

Comment: This works, but is inefficient.  There's no need to check at every position that .asp$ cannot be matched.  We only need to do the check at the end.

Comment: Works as well, I gave the answer to Jan for being more efficient. 

Thanks!