# How to Regular Expression match not having a constant at the end of a string (.net validator)

Tags: .net, regex, validation

The item referenced in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323697/regular-expression-to-match-a-string-1-characters-that-does-not-end-in-ext) does not seem to work for me.
I'm using the Regular Expression validator in .net

I need to pass validation if the input field does NOT look like this

"bagdfsdf -CONST"

When I use "(?>!-CONST)$" and ".*(?>!-CONST)$" the regular expression validator never allows it.  If I have -CONST at the end or not

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the "Regular Expression validator"? Is this ASP.Net? Are you validating in an event handler? Can you post code?

Comment: Here is the code from the aspx file...
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="R1"  ControlToValidate="Partner" ErrorMessage="Partner must have a valid employee id"  ValidationExpression="^.*(?<!-CONST)$"  />

Comment: (I took out the runat so I could work on other stuff)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(?> … )` is the syntax for an [atomic grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html). And the syntax for [look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is just `(?! … )`.

---

**Edit**   Try this regular expression instead:

```
.*$(?<!-CONST)
```

The `.*$` will consume everything and the look-behind assertion will exclude those that end with a `-CONST`.

---

**Edit**    Just for completeness’ sake: If your regular expression language does not allow look-behinds, you can also use this one using a look-ahead assertion:

```
^(.{0,5}|.*(?!-CONST).{5})$
```

Or using just alternations:

```
^(.{0,5}|.*([^-].{5}|-([^C].{4}|C([^O].{3}|O([^N].{2}|N([^S].|S[^T]))))))$
```

Comment: both  ValidationExpression=".+(?!-CONST)$"  and 
 ValidationExpression="(?!-CONST)$" 
did not work.

Comment: @Hogan: You will need a look-behind assertion since there is nothing after the end of the string.

Comment: Ah, I think the last one will work Gumbo -- The long list of [^x] almost worked, but not on strings smaller than 5 characters... using the | (ors) to make that work should be good.  I will try it on Monday.  Thanks!   I've not had any luck with the (? style operators, I think they are borked in IE's JavaScript.

Comment: @Hogan: The first alternation branch `.{0,5}` takes care of strings with up to five characters.

Comment: Just tested -- ^(.{0,5}|.*(?!-CONST).{5})$ worked - thanks Gumbo.